# SNR for good MRI imaging

Tags: biomedical-engineering

Resolution of MRI can be improved if FOV is reduced keeping other factors constant, but this reduces voxel volume,  which in turn reduces SNR. How much SNR is enough for good imaging?

Comment: Is this your question as well - two accounts, similar names?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the geometric parameters governing the image acquisition are imposed by the user. It is true that decreasing the field of view (FoV) will improve resolution provided the voxel volume is allowed to decrease - some manufacturers (e.g. Philips) give priority to the selected voxel size, so that a decrease of the FoV will be automatically accompanied by a linear drop in the matrix to keep the in-plane dimensions of the voxel size (in-plane resolution) constant. Therefore, the first sentence in the OP is not true in general.

As for how much SNR is enough, the question is unanswerable because there are no mathematical criteria for "good imaging." In CT-scanning there are Hounsfield units, but no equivalent measurements exist in MRI.

The signal-to-noise ratio is used to make relative comparisons between scanners, coils, sequences and parameter changes, but does not provide threshold values. For instance, the scanner will typically provide an estimate of the relative drop in SNR when manually modifying any given parameter. It is also known that some imaging sequences are more signal rich than others. Likewise coils (antennas) with smaller radii provide increase SNR. Finally, the administration of contrast material will increase SNR. It is all relative comparisons.

A way of looking at it is to think of SNR as "money" available to improve the quality of the image: the more the better. This increased SNR can come from actual $\\\$$ capital expenditures (3-Tesla magnet as opposed to 1.5-Tesla; or dedicated coils for small parts that are expensive), or from smart selection of imaging parameters and sequences to extract the information needed within the time constraints imposed by the organ or structure being imaged, and the patient's clinical condition.

In clinical practice, the issue is how best to utilize the SNR obtainable by the given set of scanner-coil-sequence-parameter combinations used. If the part of the anatomy is subject to motion or time-sensitive, the SNR available may be used to acquire fast (but lower resolution) images. This is referred to as increasing the 'temporal resolution'. On the other hand, if the acquisition time is not as critical, the SNR may be used to increase resolution by decreasing the voxel size either by increasing the matrix, decreasing the FoV, or decreasing the slice thickness (out-of-plane resolution).

How much? A good rule-of-thumb is to push the resolution as high as possible until the noise visible in the image starts interfering.